# How do I run procedure in oracle with some date manipulation sql in it

Tags: oracle, date, stored-procedures, date-conversion

I have created a procedure in oracle as follows:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE SP_X_AVERAGE
(
    profile out SYS_REFCURSOR,
    rx out SYS_REFCURSOR,
)
as
BEGIN


  open profile for
        select
            avg(to_number(profile_netassets)) AS netassets
        from 
            fgp;


  open rx for
      select 
          avg(to_number(a_price)) as twr 
      from 
          r_x
      where 
            gq_date <= add_months(to_date(sysdate, 'mm/dd/yyyy'), -12);


END SP_X_AVERAGE;
```

It doesn't run, giving the following error:

```
ORA-01843: not a valid month
```

If I remove the where condition in the second sql then it runs successfully.

Altering a session using an sql in the same procedure doesnot work too.

Please help.

I am running this procedure in sql-developer (ubuntu Oneiric 11)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SYSDATE is already a DATE so you don't need to apply TO_DATE() to it.  However, more recent versions of Oracle are tolerant of such things and handle them gracefully.

So that leaves the matter of `r_x.gq_date`: what data type is that?  If it is a string then the chances are you have values in there which will not cast to a date, or at last don't match your default NLS_FORMAT.

---

"we have to keep it as "VARCHAR2(40 BYTE)" it is having date in it like this : '1/2/2003'"

Bingo.  Is that the same as your NLS_DATE_FORMAT?  If not you will need to cast the column:

```
to_date(gq_date, 'mm/dd/yyyy')  <= add_months(sysdate, -12);
```

This may not solve your problem if the column contains strings which aren't in that format.  This is a common side-effect of using strings to hold things which aren't strings.

Comment: a_price being explicitly cast to a number also looks suspicious -- it couldn't be that everything is a character type could it?

Comment: a table called "r_x" is suspicious also

Comment: @APC: due to some reasons we have to keep it as "VARCHAR2(40 BYTE)" it is having date in it like this : '1/2/2003'. Query number 2 runs perfectly fine in a sql-sheet but it gives error when I execute it in a procedure using sql developer.

Comment: Dreadful. So the date is stored as text, and in a format where greater-than and less-than operators are not even valid. you'll have to convert the column to a date with To_Date() and compare against that then, optionally creating a function-based index to avoid performance problems.

Comment: yeah, that's my NLS_DATE_FORMAT :), that worked.. Thanks.. :)